# Connect to Netezza in Spark: No suitable driver error (but driver present in SPARK_CLASSPATH)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, driver, netezza

I've added my Netezza jar (nzjdbc3.jar) in SPARK_CLASSPATH before launching spark-shell.

This is how i'm connecting to Netezza in Scala:

```
scala>> val mytable = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:netezza://host:port/dbName?user=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx", "dbtable" -> "table_name"))
```

I keep getting the famous "no suitable driver" error. I got JDBC connections to work successfully for Oracle, Sybase, PostGres and MySQL; the problem is only with Netezza.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Depending on the driver, you want to try adding the `driver` property to the map (with as value the name of the Netezza JDBC driver).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel add your comment as an answer. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your driver is not a JDBC 4 driver, which means it isn't automatically loaded (you might want to check if there is a newer version available).

You can instruct the driver to be loaded by adding the `driver` property to the map with as value the name of the Netezza JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked perfectly.                     sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "xxxxx", "dbtable" -> "yyyyy", "driver" -> "org.netezza.Driver"))